# Update-database with code first and foreign key that's required not working

Tags: ef-code-first, foreign-key-relationship, seeding

When using code first i have this scenario:

I have an existing database where tables are created with Code first.

Know suddenly there needs to be a change in the program and there is a new table that is related to the Primary table (with existing data in it).

Example there is a table "Package" and a the new table is "PackageState"

Steps

1. Create new domain Packagestate with some properties.
2. Add property packagestate (FK) in Package domain.(P) ***Note that the packagestate is required.***
3. In the seeding class i add some data for the packagestate

From this point i have a problem, because the value is required, and the seeding method is only executed after update.

How do you solve this with code first?

Because it's possible that there is a new migration file as well.

I need some feedback on this thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You must make your foreign key nullable and update your database
after that you can run your seed.
and after all you should change your foreign key to not null.

Comment: I know ... but i noticed that it's not possible in 1 update-database command. -> and with seed action.
My goal was to avoid multiple deployments.